# Trigger that updates stock levels after a sale - MySQL Workbench

Tags: triggers, mysql-workbench

I am trying to create a trigger called 'stockupdate' that updates 'quantity_available' when a new order is placed on my order_line_item_table.

Tables and columns required: stock_table.quantity_available (Represents Stock) order_line_item_table.sale_quantity (Represents each order placed)

I have used the below code to create the trigger, however when I insert a new order to check the trigger is working, the stock_table.quantity_available figure does not update and I am not sure why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
DELIMITER $$ 
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS stockupdate; 
CREATE TRIGGER stockupdate 
AFTER INSERT ON order_line_item_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE stock_table 
    SET quantity_available = (quantity_available - NEW.sale_quantity)
    WHERE product_id = NEW.product_id;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I am expecting the quantity_available to decrease by the sale_quantity amount when a new order is placed on the order_line_item_table